# Radiobutton value always ON in v-for loop VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form in which users can add unlimited addresses. Now each address field set contains a radiobutton, to say which address is primary.

The problem is, even when it's not selected, it will return 'ON';

Here's my code:

```
<div class="" v-for="address in addresses">
                        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('address.*.billing_company_name')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" v-model="address.billing_company_name" class="form-control" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('address.*.billing_to')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">T,A.V</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" v-model="address.billing_to" class="form-control" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('address.*.billing_address')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adres</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" v-model="address.billing_address" class="form-control" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('address.*.billing_address')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Postcode</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" v-model="address.billing_postcode" class="form-control" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('address.*.billing_city')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Plaats</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" v-model="address.billing_city" class="form-control" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('address.*.billing_country')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Land</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select v-model="address.billing_country" class="form-control">
                            @foreach($countries as $code => $country)
                            <option value="{{$code}}">{{$country}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                            </select></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('primary')) has-error @endif">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Primair adres?</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10"><label class="control-label">
                            <input type="radio" name="t" v-model="address.primary" /></label> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" v-on:click="removeAddress($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Adres verwijderen</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
```

In my vue instance i have the following:

```
var V = new Vue({
    el:"#form",
    data: addresses: [
        {
            billing_company_name: '',
            billing_to: '',
            billing_address: '',
            billing_postcode: '',
            billing_city: '',
            billing_country: '',
            primary: ''
        }]
}
```

I have given the field a name value, because without selecting 1 radio will make them all selected.

I have tried adding `track-by=$index` but that didn't work either.

The results when i submit the form, with 1 radio button selected:

```
  "addresses" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "billing_company_name" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_to" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_address" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_postcode" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_city" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_country" => "AD"
      "primary" => "on"
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▼
      "billing_company_name" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_to" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_address" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_postcode" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_city" => "http://www.google.nl"
      "billing_country" => "DZ"
      "primary" => "on"
    ]
  ]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you attach a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmmm, found some similar problem here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-v-for-radio-list-and-checked-value

Comment: Don't have time for a fiddle today, will provide one tomorrow!